# Select Table range with variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Macro that fetches a table name and then styles it.  However it keeps failing at

```
Range("Table" & ActiveSheet.Name & "[#All]").Select
```

How do I select all of the table based on its variable name?  The table is called Table22 (as the sheet tab is called 22)

Full code

```
With Range("A1")

.Parent.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(.End(xlDown), .End(xlToRight)), , xlYes).Name = "Table" & ActiveSheet.Name
Range("Table" & ActiveSheet.Name & "[#All]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table" & ActiveSheet.Name).TableStyle = "TableStyleDark1"
```

Comment: [Avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) to begin with. And work with `ListObject`s, which is what a table is.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the surrounding code.

Comment: `Dim tbl As ListObject`, `Set tbl = .Parent.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(.End(xlDown), .End(xlToRight)), , xlYes)`. Then you can modify `tbl` to your heart's content, including changing its `.Name` and its `.TableStyle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Avoid using `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)
- Use a [`ListObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject) variable.
- [`ListObjects.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobjects.add) has an optional *TableStyleName* parameter.

```
With ActiveSheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = .ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, _
                  Source:=.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, _
                  XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes, _
                  TableStyleName:="TableStyleDark1")
    tbl.Name = "Table" & .Name
End With
```